# React antd form disable submit button

Tags: reactjs, antd

How could I disable form submit button using antd

Form validations work, but I need to visually disable form submit button when validation fails

[image]

This is a stackblitz url
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-z5d6tr?file=Hello.tsx

Comment: here is working url https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-z5d6tr?file=Hello.tsx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found some elegant way to perform this

```
<Form.Item shouldUpdate className="submit">
  {() => (
    <Button
      type="primary"
      htmlType="submit"
      disabled={
        !form.isFieldsTouched(true) ||
        form.getFieldsError().filter(({ errors }) => errors.length)
          .length > 0
      }
    >
      Log in
    </Button>
  )}
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Can I create a variable with that disabled value ?
And where can I declare it, where to put it?

Comment: It is not working with current code, and it is working after remove the true value from `form.isFieldTouched()`

Comment: this is not working :/

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to paste here my solution in case anyone finds it useful.
Note; this solution uses the hook `Form.useForm()` and the callback `onFieldsChange`.

The validation is not included in this excerpt. But the idea is that when the form changes (any field) it will set the submit button (in this case inside the Modal) to disabled/enabled.

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const [form] = useForm();
  const [disabledSave, setDisabledSave] = useState(true);
  
  const handleFormChange = () => {
    const hasErrors = form.getFieldsError().some(({ errors }) => errors.length);
    setDisabledSave(hasErrors);
  }
  
  return (
    <Modal okButtonProps={{ disabled: disabledSave }} onOk={form.submit}>
      <Form onFieldsChange={handleFormChange} form={form}>
        <Item name="username" label="username">
          <Input />
        </Item>
        <Item name="password" label="password">
          <Input />
        </Item>
      </Form>
    </Modal>
  )
};
```

Comment: I needed the disable for the okButtonProps on the Modal and this worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I found a nice solution here that doesn't involve any additional state.  If you wrap your submit button in a `Form.Item` like this, it should disable it until all required fields are completed.  The rest of the form would remain the same.

```
<Form.Item
 noStyle
 shouldUpdate
>
  {({ getFieldsValue }) => {
    const { username, password } = getFieldsValue();
    const formIsComplete = !!username && !!password;
    return (
      <Button
         type="primary"
         htmlType="submit"
         disabled={!formIsComplete}
       >
         Log In
       </Button>
    );
  }}
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { UnlockOutlined, UserOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Button, Card, Form, Input, Layout, Space } from "antd";
import { ValidateErrorEntity } from "rc-field-form/es/interface";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

interface LoginForm {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

const Hello = () => {
  // Create State
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const onFinish = (values: LoginForm) => {
  };

  

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo: ValidateErrorEntity) => {
    setError(errorInfo); // set the state if error
  };

  // When the user starts type set state to false
  const handleChange = e => e.target.value && setError(false);

  return (
    <Layout className="login">
      <Card className="card">
        <Form
          onFinish={onFinish}
          onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
          size="large"
          layout="vertical"
        >
          <Space direction="vertical" size="middle">
            <Form.Item
              name="username"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "Please input your username!" }
              ]}
            >
              {/*Listening to change event*/ }
              <Input onChange={handleChange} prefix={<UserOutlined />} placeholder="Username" />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item
              name="password"
              rules={[
                { required: true, message: "Please input your password!" }
              ]}
            >
              {/*Listening to change event*/ }
              <Input.Password
                onChange={handleChange}
                prefix={<UnlockOutlined />}
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item className="submit">
              {/*Disable button only if error is true*/ }
              <Button disabled={error && true} type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                Login
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Space>
        </Form>
      </Card>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me!

```
const [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);
...
...
const onValuesChange = async (values: any) => {
  try {
    await form.validateFields();
    setFormError(false);
  } catch (err) {
    setFormError(true);
  }
}
...
...
<Form form={form} onValuesChange={onValuesChange} />
...
...
<Form.Item label="First Name" name='firstName' required={true} rules={[{ required: true, min: 3, max: 50,
  message: 'First name is required, min 3 and max 50 characters!' }]}>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
...
...
<Button disabled={formError}>Save</Button>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a good solution without any additional re-render(re-evaluated) cost!!
I control button component with Form.Item because it passes the Value prop to the button and when the button props changed React re-evaluate that, so if we use this Value prop inside the button for disabling and enabling, the problem will be solved!!
for example:

```
<Form
    name="form"
    form={form}
    initialValues={{
      button: 1,
    }}
    onFieldsChange={() => {
      // button field value = true if there isn't an error
      form.setFieldValue(
        "button",
       //Attention: put all fields except the button field
        !form.isFieldsTouched(["input"], true) ||
          form.getFieldsError().filter(({ errors }) => {
            return errors.length;
          }).length > 0
      );
    }}
  >
    <Form.Item
      name="input"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
        },
      ]}
    >
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item name="button">
      <CustomButton>login</CustomButton>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
function CustomButton({children, ...rest}) {
  return (
    <Button
      {...rest}
      disabled={rest.value}
    >
    {children}
   </Button>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have handled this way

1. create a state

```js
const [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);
```

2. create onChange function

```js
  const onValuesChange = async (values: any) => {
    try {
      await form.validateFields();
      setFormError(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setFormError(true);
    }
  }
```

3. attach onChange function to form

```
<Form onValuesChange={onValuesChange} > </Form>
```

4. on the submit button

```
<Button type="primary" size="large" htmlType="submit" disabled={!form.isFieldsTouched() || formError}>Save</Button>
```

you can also use !form.isFieldsTouched(true)

Working example: https://github.com/Aravin/Invoice-Nest/blob/main/code/client/component/Invoice/InvoiceForm.tsx#L451

This worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

I did some edits here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-spuhdd?file=Hello.tsx

Sum up of what I've done :

1. I created hooks username, password and disabled
2. Everytime the user changes username and password, if these fields are empty, disabled is set as false.
3. If the onFinishFailed is executed, this disabled is set to true.
4. When the disabled is at true, the button becomes disabled. If disabled property becomes false, the button becomes clickable again.

Comment: yeah its working, but thing is when we have some additional rules, this will be more complexed though, Im looking for some kind of `react-hook-form` approach, anyway thanks