# How to use Antd InternalFormInstance to validate form without display of UI Errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, antd

I am trying to disable the form submit button until the validation is fully passed.

I have come across the threads regarding this topic.

This thread helps to trigger validation without display of UI errors:
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/25993

The below code works within the hoc of my footer button wrapper, but it is verifying for all fields to be touched and even applicable for non-required fields, which is not right and expected.

```js
<Form.Item shouldUpdate>
    {() => (
      <Button
        type="primary"
        htmlType="submit"
        disabled={
          !!form
            .getFieldsError()
            .filter(({ errors }) => errors.length).length
        }
      >
        Log in
      </Button>
    )}
</Form.Item>
```

Unfortunately, https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/23281 thread is full of Chinese and I cannot understand it.

My existing form.validateFields refers to formInstance, but it is referring to: InternalFormInstance.

How to import this and validate? Is it really supported in antd 4 version?

**CodeSandbox link:** https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-merkle-21izz?file=/src/withFormWrapperHOC.tsx

Example code as a reference will be helpful!

The form validation miserably fails when select list is included. Form onChange or onChangeValues don't work; when we dig more the !form.isFieldsTouched(true) is always true even when there is no validation rule associated with Select List.

**Ref ticket:** https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/8436

It looks like Antd has some open issues with Rc-select api integrations and also which is not exposed.

Should we really consider Antd or any other form validation?

Comment: No luck here? Has none tried to disable the form button till validation pass?

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox to have a better look at the issue?

Comment: @diedu - https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-merkle-21izz?file=/src/withFormWrapperHOC.tsx. The Button is now disabling onClick, but it has to happen on component mount as well as with exact form validation without displaying UI errors.

Comment: does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010399/react-antd-form-disable-submit-button

Comment: @Diedu - the same piece of submit button code from answer i have. It doesn't.

Comment: you're not checking if fields have been touched `!form.isFieldsTouched(true)` that would disable the button at first render

Comment: @diedu - Adding that works fine for something, but not happening for all form fields like select list multiple tags

Comment: Also, form.isFieldsTouched() always returns true when select list is rendered.

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa please check submitted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For disabling validation on first render you can use Ref workaround

```js
const isMounting = React.useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (isMounting.current) {
    const disableStatus = !!form
      .getFieldsError()
      .filter(({ errors }) => errors.length).length;
    setIsDisabled(disableStatus);
  }
  else {
    isMounting.current = true
  }
}, [form]);
```

---

Another option would to disable login button till all the form inputs are filled and then validate with Login

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Select } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const { Option } = Select;

export function withFormWrapper(WrappedComponent: any) {
  return (props: any) => {
    const [form] = Form.useForm();
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);

    function fieldIsEmpty(field) {
      let fieldValue = form.getFieldValue(field.name.join("."));
      return (
        fieldValue === undefined || [].concat(fieldValue).join().trim() === ""
      );
    }

    function fieldHasError(field) {
      return field.errors.length > 0;
    }

    function isValid() {
      const fields = form
        .getFieldsError()
        .filter((field) => fieldIsEmpty(field) || fieldHasError(field));

      console.log(fields);
      setIsDisabled(fields.length > 0);
    }

    const validate = () => {
      form
        .validateFields()
        .then((values: any) => {
          console.log("success");
        })
        .catch((errorInfo: any) => {
          console.log("failure");
        });
    };

    return (
      <Form form={form} onChange={isValid}>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        <Form.Item name="gender" label="Gender" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
          <Select
            placeholder="Select a option and change input text above"
            onChange={isValid}
            allowClear
          >
            <Option value="male">male</Option>
            <Option value="female">female</Option>
            <Option value="other">other</Option>
          </Select>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button
            type="default"
            htmlType="submit"
            onClick={() => form.resetFields()}
          >
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item shouldUpdate>
          {() => (
            <Button
              onClick={validate}
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
              disabled={isDisabled}
            >
              Log in
            </Button>
          )}
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  };
}
```

Here working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-framework-4x60d?file=/src/withFormWrapperHOC.tsx)

---

With `Form.Provider` `onFormChange` validation can be fired for Select Component

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Select } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const { Option } = Select;

export function withFormWrapper(WrappedComponent: any) {
  return (props: any) => {
    const [form] = Form.useForm();
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);

    function fieldIsEmpty(field) {
      let fieldValue = form.getFieldValue(field.name.join("."));
      return (
        fieldValue === undefined || [].concat(fieldValue).join().trim() === ""
      );
    }

    function fieldHasError(field) {
      return field.errors.length > 0;
    }

    function isValid() {
      const fields = form
        .getFieldsError()
        .filter((field) => fieldIsEmpty(field) || fieldHasError(field));

      setIsDisabled(fields.length > 0);
    }

    const validate = () => {
      form
        .validateFields()
        .then((values: any) => {
          console.log("success");
        })
        .catch((errorInfo: any) => {
          console.log("failure");
        });
    };

    return (
      <Form.Provider onFormChange={isValid}>
        <Form form={form}>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
          <Form.Item
            name="gender"
            label="Gender"
            rules={[{ required: true }]}
            shouldUpdate
          >
            <Select
              placeholder="Select a option and change input text above"
              allowClear
            >
              <Option value="male">male</Option>
              <Option value="female">female</Option>
              <Option value="other">other</Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="Tags" label="Tags" shouldUpdate>
            <Select
              mode="tags"
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              placeholder="Tags Mode"
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              {children}
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button
              type="default"
              htmlType="submit"
              onClick={() => form.resetFields()}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item shouldUpdate>
            {() => (
              <Button
                onClick={validate}
                type="primary"
                htmlType="submit"
                disabled={isDisabled}
              >
                Log in
              </Button>
            )}
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Form.Provider>
    );
  };
}
```

Here working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-banzai-1782w?file=/src/withFormWrapperHOC.tsx)

Comment: Can you add select dropdown list and give a try. This i also have made it work earlier, but it miserably fails when you get select list.

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa can you share minimal working code that you created

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa I have update the answer and added Select component

Comment: thanks for taking your time and responding. But still it doesnt fulfil the requirement. Because you are calling onChange method from Select not from Form onChange or onChangeValues. 
The reason i raised this question, we need to now update the submit button to disable status. I cannot modify the components individually. Anything should be done within HOCWrapper. Hope you got this point. I have tried and did what ever you have made so far. But that is not the ideal solution which i am looking at.

Comment: Try if you can achieve that with form onchange or onValuesChange at the earliest as the bounty is getting expired soon. I can reward for your efforts if you find any quick jugaad

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa I have updated answer

Comment: Great! What if the gender has no rules defined? The validations should only happen within the ruleset not for all fields :)

Comment: I have updated this answer link with: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-sound-v7etf?file=/src/withFormWrapperHOC.tsx with select multiple list also. The problem with these two only. And very importantly if there is no rule of mandatory, it should not bother. Same with update item, when there is no change the button should be disabled.

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa I can't see multiple selects in the shared example can you check and confirm the shared link.

Comment: I am rewarding you before the bounty gets wasted. The answer is not complete. I have updated the link, please re-check

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa can you share updated link I am still not able to see changes in the share link check [here](https://imgur.com/a/b7VdxRk).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-ramanujan-itjrg?file=/src/withFormWrapperHOC.tsx. Here is the updated link

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa updated the answer with fix

Comment: Can you provide the link, please?

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa here the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-banzai-1782w?file=/src/withFormWrapperHOC.tsx) and also added select with tag mode in answer

Comment: Thanks, if you observe the Tags do not have any rules defined. Hence it is not mandatory to fill. So button should be enabled without entering tags right?

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa the validation is not for rules it for if user has filled all the inputs or not, validation would be fired when login button is clicked and error would be shown then only.

Comment: The submit button depends on the validation, if there are 10 fields with mandate of 2, it has to consider those 2 not complete 10 :) My question clearly says it has to validate without displaying UI errors. I have nowhere mentioned to disable when the fields are not filled :)

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa antd does not have any method write now which validates and does not show error that's why i mentioned in the implementation that another way would be to disable all inputs until filled and then validate with single click but you can also validate all of inputs with [joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.2) if you want when the `onFormChange` is being called.